# Filenames of source files when creating .md in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: markdown, visual-studio-2022

Is there any option in Visual Studio to quickly copy the name of the file I'm working on (looking at in the editor) to the Windows clipboard? The context menu of the tab offers "Copy Full Path," but I would need only the file name with extension.
Would it help me when writing .md documentation.

Or is there some other efficient way to make a reference to a position in a file without the need to write everything out. For example, creating a Link to file by simply switching to the file, placing the cursor, and clicking a button in the toolbar?
To create: `[some comment](App.xaml.cs#L14)`

And the last question: is it possible to create a bookmark (tag) in a .cs file that could be referenced in a .md file?

Thank you for the recommendations and advice